# Question about the quadratic deviation of energy in the thermodynamic limit

Tags: energy, statistical-mechanics, partition-function

We know that 
$$  \langle ( E_j - \langle E_j \rangle )^2 \rangle = - \frac{\partial}{\partial \beta} \langle E_j \rangle  $$
And in the thermodynamic limit $ \langle E_j \rangle \longrightarrow U $

In the book *Introduction to Statistical Physics* of Silvio R. A. Salinas, there's the following text:

> Making the identification between the expected value of energy and the
>   internal thermal dynamic energy, we have $$ \langle ( E_j - \langle
>  E_j \rangle )^2 \rangle = -\frac{\partial}{\partial \beta} U = k_B T^2
>  \frac{\partial U}{\partial T} = Nk_B T^2 c_V \geq 0 $$

Where did that $ k_B T^2 \frac{\partial U}{\partial T} $ come from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$ T= \frac{1}{\beta} \implies \frac {\partial T}{\partial \beta} = - \frac {1}{\beta^2} = - T^2$$

hence, using the chain rule:

$$ - \frac {\partial U}{\partial \beta} = - \frac {\partial U}{\partial T} \frac {\partial T}{\partial \beta} = T^2 \frac {\partial U}{\partial T} $$